# How to add multiple segues from one viewController

Tags: ios, xcode, segue, viewcontroller

I have a UI view controller(viewControllerOne) with a table view in it. I have a segue from a button in the cell to another viewController (viewControllerTwo).

This works fine.
now , i have a third view controller and want to have a segue from another button in View Controller one . 
How to have multiple segues from one view controller to go to different viewController.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First segue should be between the VC itself ( not a button inside the cell ) to the destinationVC  as to be able to send data in `prepareforSegue` , so from the yellow icon of VC1 drag to both VC2 and VC3 and give a segue identifier like **toSecond** & **toThird** respectively then in code do

```
// change segue identifier if you want to third 
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSecond ", sender:nil)
```

Comment: After that I used  if  else statements in prepare for segue and it worked fine. 

Answer (score 1):

Segues inside `UITableViewCell` should be done programmatically. Use the `didSelectCell at indexPath` method. When this is called, you should perform a segue based on the indexPath. I personally recommend having an array of structs to keep track of the `UITableViewCells`. For example:

```
struct tableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell
    var segue: String
}

var cells: Array<Array<tableViewCell>> = [];

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: cells[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].segue);
}
```

Sorry if there are any typos, this code was not written in xcode.